# What should our domain name be?

Tags: discussion, beta-essentials

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name english.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names. (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

Per [the seven essential meta questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/):

> The search for domain name typically
> starts very early during the private
> beta. And for good reason: Naming is
> really, really hard. Add to that, the
> rare commodity that good domain names
> have become, and there’s no wonder why
> there is such angst that this process
> not be made public.
>
> But rather than saying “we can’t
> discuss this at all,” we take our
> chances by having these discussions
> openly in the community. So far, we
> haven’t seen any problems. But, if a
> muse visits you in the night and
> personally entrusts you as the keeper
> of the perfect, amazingly good domain
> name, feel free to [email me privately](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino).
>
> When considering domain names, keep
> these basic guidelines in mind:
>
> - The domain name should be available.
>   You can check domain name availability
>   [here](http://www.whois.net/).
> - Prefer dot-com names over other
>   top-level domains.
> - Prefer non-hyphenated names.

Comment: This kind of depends on the answer to this question: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/45/do-we-need-a-site-manifesto

Comment: [Not related but related](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15538/2085).

Answer (score 19):

## Lexicalia.com

Status: owned by user [nohat](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/39/nohat), who is willing to transfer ownership of the domain.

This is a made-up word, made from combining the Greek root *lexicos*, referring to words, with the suffix *‑alia*, denoting a collection of items related to a particular area of activity or interest. Thus, *Lexicalia* is a collection of items related to words.

Comment: Not bad at all!

Comment: Boooooooooooooooooo!!!

Comment: *(sings)* Leeexicali Rose...

Comment: What a lovely sequence of letters.

Comment: I quite like this name actually. Even those who are skilled in the English language should be happy with this 'poetic license'.

Comment: Also, this makes for a great descriptor of site users. *Lexicalians* !

Comment: I love the sound of this name, but it seems too focused on words (as opposed to phrases, grammar, usage, etc).

Comment: I don't like it because it seems way too self-congratulatingly clever. I realize *-alia* is a standard suffix, but it is just too close to *genitalia* for me. There just aren't a lot of words out there that use it, and those that do are very rare. *Paraphernalia*, *latrinalia*, *kitchenalia*–most of these are uncommon and all are somewhat hoity-toity in feel. Is that what you want the "feel" of the site to be? "Stack Overflow" doesn't describe that site. Instead it calls on an experience that all programmers have, and at that, a negative one!

Comment: So I question this name because it just doesn't feel accessible to me. Don't describe the site. Attract people to it.

Answer (score 8):

### participle.com

(parked, placeholder)

I like the fact that it evokes "participate".

Answer (score 7):

How about **Present Perfect**?

*presentperfect.com* is not available, but the registrar is Network Solutions, which makes me think it might be easier to get than other squatted names.

EDIT:
Ugh, there seems to be content there now.  It's just a Flash placeholder, but it's probably enough to disqualify the name.

Comment: Seems to me that "not available" has to disqualify it, unless there's a specific acceptable listed price.

Comment: An excellent name to attract native speakers. However, to people who learn English by browsing YouTube and Digg, it sounds like yet another online gift shop. In fact, there is [present-perfect.de](http://www.present-perfect.de/), who are selling promotional items.

Comment: @dave, I used to think that, but The Bosses have spoken otherwise.  "If the name is registered but is being 'squatted,' i.e., there’s something there, it’s just not anything worthwhile, ask the owner if they would sell. If it’s available for a reasonable amount of money, and it’s a great name, and the community loves it, we may even be able to buy it." -Joel ( [source](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/) )

Comment: @Reg, that website makes me a little sad.

Comment: There is a fully-fledged website there now. I think we're out of luck.

Comment: In principle we could try presentperfect.org or presentperfect.net etc., but there's the risk of confusion.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, SOIS's policy is strongly against anything other than `.com`.

Answer (score 7):

## grammarpower.com

available

Comment: -1 This is such an uncreative name which does the exact opposite of what it's intended to do.

Comment: No, that would be grammerpowar.com!

Answer (score 5):

English Enthusiast

## EnglishEnthusiast.com

Available.

Comment: -1 This is too dweeby: do you really want to tell people "I'm an English enthusiast"?

Answer (score 5):

## EnglishLangua.ge

Available, again not a .com

Answer (score 5):

## **WordOverflow.com**

available

Answer (score 4):

## slipperywords.com

available

Answer (score 3):

Since there may be — again, IANAL — copyright issues with `OxfordComma.com`, how about the alternate term

## SerialComma.com

It's registered, but there's no site there; not even one of those ad-laden placeholders.  And the registration expires in a few months, for what that's worth.

Comment: SerialKiller sounds better, but that's just me.

Answer (score 3):

### redcomment.com

(available)

Answer (score 2):

### grammunity.com

(available)

Answer (score 1):

## OxfordComma.com

Available

(http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/page/oxfordcomma)

Comment: -1: Oxford is pretty sure to be trademarked with respect to English language.

Comment: @Shinto, Oxford is a city, a university, a type of shirt, a brand of dictionary (which is probably what you were thinking of); I don't think it's trademarkable.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus: if you open any book published by OUP you'll find the following words: "OXFORD and OXFORD ENGLISH are registered trade marks of Oxford University Press in the UK and certain other countries"

Comment: @Shinto, that's incredible.  I guess I should leave this one for the lawyers, huh?

Answer (score 1):

### circledred.com

(in line with stack overflow and server fault, a common way to signal an error in grammar.)

Comment: I like circledred.com, but it's not the most readable domain name. I've suggested 'redcomment.com' instead.

Comment: I like the idea but when I read it it makes me think of people who are afraid of circles (circle dread)

Answer (score 1):

## englishmastered.com

available

Comment: I read this as 'English Mustard' - Not gonna down vote it though - i love mustard...mmm..lovely with ham.

Answer (score 1):

### verbalessences.com

(available)

Comment: This one probably shouldn't be taken too seriously.

Answer (score 1):

## TongueTips.com

available

Answer (score 0):

elu.com is not available, but is not used either.

## EL&U

English Language & Usage

## elu.com

Answer (score 0):

## MiddleVerb.com

Available

## LinkingVerb.com

For sale

Answer (score 0):

## IntentionalAmbiguity.com

Available

Comment: Or InternationalAmbiguity???

Comment: and by the time you type it...

Answer (score 0):

### VerbPhrase.com

Available, easy-to-type

Answer (score 0):

## ProofRed.Com

Not available but no content and created 11 years ago.

It's a pun, not technically incorrect though certainly not spelled the way it sounds (a possible problem), still hints at what the site is about, and is short and sweet.

Answer (score 0):

## SentenceFragment.Com

Available.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was **GrammarGeeks.com** but this seems taken by someone who does copy-editing as a business. Along the same lines,

### GrammarNerds.com

whois suggests that the domain is available.

Answer (score 0):

## SoItIsSaid.com

available

SoItsSaid.com

SoItIsSaid.com

SoItWasSaid.com

AndSoItWasSaid.com

all available

Comment: Various others along that theme have the dot nets available - 

SomePeopleSay  , SomeMightSay , YouDontSay (.com for sale)

Comment: I think a little bit of sick came into my mouth with the its/it's confusion in this domain. ;)

Comment: haha...yes i did wonder if that was going to be an issue

Comment: i moved SoItsSaid.com down a peg in response to its inducement of sick

Answer (score 0):

## MonkeysWithTypewriters.com

registered but for sale

The powerful 'collective intelligence' of stack exchange sites reminds me of the [Infinite Monkey Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) which states that:

A monkey hitting keys on a typewriter for an infinite amount of time will almost surely type the complete works of William Shakespeare.

---

Answer (score -1):

## linguafran.ca

or

## lingua.fran.ca

Both exist, but point nowhere

Comment: not a .com, but fits

Comment: Sadly engli.sh is taken and not for sale

Comment: I've never really been a fan of the term “lingua franca”. It’s an Italian name that means “French language”. Not English-centric enough for my tastes.

Comment: And who knows whether or not English will stay so.

Comment: @nohat Or rather "lingua franca" is an Italian name that means ["Frankish tongue"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lingua+franca): "a stripped-down Italian peppered with Spanish, French, Greek, Arabic, and Turkish words".

Answer (score -1):

## HowDoISayThatAgain.Com

Comment: How about `iforgotthedomainname.com`?

Answer (score -2):

**NoPassiveVoice.com**
available

Answer (score -2):

## LoanWords.com

Available

Answer (score -2):

## AlternateSpelling.com

For sale

Answer (score -2):

### grammaticaltechnicalities.com

available

Comment: I don't think this site is nearly pedantic enough for that name to be appropriate (darnit).

Answer (score -2):

Since there may be — again, IANAL — copyright issues with `OxfordComma.com`, how about the lesser-used term

## HarvardComma.com

It's available, though the term is less common than "Oxford comma" or "serial comma" as far as I know.

Answer (score -2):

### englishbad.com

since badenglish.com isn't available

Comment: `ThisBadName.com` or `NoUseThis.OK/?=ItStupid`

Answer (score -2):

## FindingEnglish.com

Available

I'd use this site to find the correct word for something or find the correct usage etc.

Answer (score -2):

## QuestionMyEnglish.com

available

Answer (score -3):

## ReadabilityEdit.com

Available

Answer (score -3):

## FindingTheWord.com

available

Comment: I'm surprised this has 2 downvotes. I'm interested to know why it is so distasteful. Please add a comment to enlighten me.

Answer (score -3):

## FluentOnglish.com

available

## CorrectMyOnglish.com

available

Cos they are so hilarious

Answer (score -4):

## smittenbyfire.com

available

Comment: Can you explain this name, Andrew? I don't get it.

Comment: @delete `moc.erifybnettims`... Nope.